# Laravel Bouncer $user->getRoles not working

Tags: laravel

I am trying to access user roles in using below code

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->getRoles();
```

But it is giving below error:

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRoles does not exist."

We're using the default Auth user model

Comment: instead of `$user->getRoles()` try `$user->roles`

Comment: Did you add getRoles() method in your Model?

Comment: We are using Bouncer package for managing roles and abilities

Answer (score 1):

The `getRoles()` method was only introduced recently on the master branch, before that you need to use `$user->roles`. I asked this very question on the repo:

[Github Link](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/issues/281#event-1597872797)